# Is it possible to calculate Absolute Salinity and Potential temperature within netcdf/raster brick?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am using the data from [2004-2018 RG Argo Temperature Climatology and 2004-2018 RG Argo Salinity Climatology](https://sio-argo.ucsd.edu/RG_Climatology.html).

```
Mean_temp <- brick("/Users/RG_ArgoClim_Temp.nc", stopIfNotEqualSpaced = FALSE, varname = "ARGO_TEMPERATURE_MEAN")
Mean_sal <- brick("/Users/RG_ArgoClim_Salinity_2019.nc", stopIfNotEqualSpaced = FALSE, varname = "ARGO_SALINITY_MEAN")
plot(Mean_temp, 1)
plot(Mean_sal, 1)
```

I then merged/added the means with the monthly anomaly files (showing January here but I did it for Jan - Dec)

```
 GridArgo_Jan_2022 <- brick("/Users/RG_ArgoClim_202201_2019.nc", stopIfNotEqualSpaced = FALSE, varname = "ARGO_TEMPERATURE_ANOMALY")

 January <- Mean_temp+GridArgo_Jan_2022
```

Output:

class      : RasterBrick

dimensions : 145, 360, 52200, 58  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)

resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)

extent     : 20, 380, -65, 80  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
source     : r_tmp_2023-07-19_170642_60337_07632.grd

names      :     layer.1,     layer.2,     layer.3,     layer.4,     layer.5,
layer.6,     layer.7,     layer.8,     layer.9,    layer.10,    layer.11,    layer.12,    layer.13,    layer.14,    layer.15, ...

min values : -2.01200003, -2.00000003, -1.97000001, -1.85099995, -1.66900000, -1.68600006, -1.84400004, -1.91899998, -2.02700004, -2.06600001, -1.97199994, -1.74499995, -1.72000006, -1.68599999, -1.64399999, ...

max values :      31.205,      31.175,      31.103,      30.934,      30.640,      30.501,      30.343,      30.352,      30.329,      30.211,      30.031,      29.819,      29.767,      29.634,      29.282, ...

I need to calculate [potential temperature](https://rdrr.io/cran/oce/man/swTheta.html) but to do this I have to first calculate [potential salinity](http://www.teos-10.org/pubs/gsw/html/gsw_SA_from_SP.html).

Do I need to convert everything to a data frame then create a new column?

I tried doing it this way:

```
 df <- as.data.frame(Mean_temp, xy = TRUE)
 head(df)
```

but I get latitude on the first column, longitude on the second column but the pressure is at the top row.

1. Is there a way to manipulate the data frame so that I can calculate absolute salinity? gsw_SA_from_SP(SP,p,long,lat) where SP is the salinity measurement, p is the pressure, long and lat.
2. Can I 'import' the absolute salinity results to calculate potential temperature? There are currently 2 files (Mean_temp, and Mean_sal). Is the best way to merge the files?